# FQL / Graph Api : Delete friends who belongs to particular group / list

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-fql, facebook-apps

I am working on a facebook task

1. delete friends who belongs to particular list
2. delete friends who belongs to particular group
3. block friends who belongs to particular list
4. block friends who belongs to particular group

Which api is better for this purpose fql or graph api.

Please suggest your ideas to get this task done.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot block or delete from friends via the API so none of these paths are viable.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=731211650233556&pnref=story

You are probably wrong. Apparently, there's an app that lets you delete all of your inactivated friends programatically

Comment: @Ahmedov no, Khalil is a well known greyhat hacker. The methods he uses aren't from the official API.